# Sublime Text autocomplete comments

Tags: autocomplete

Sublime Text currently suggests any word that exists in the active text file (as well as other, language-specific words).

Is there a way to exclude words in comment blocks from being suggested by the autocomplete?

May be useful:

- Sublime Text 3
- Python (with Anaconda plugin)

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: I never solved it...

Comment: it should be just a simple implementation, just don't index lines that start with the comment character. We should open an issue in ST3 github